# Wordpress show only upcoming items

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress script that shows agenda items. I need to show only the items that are upcoming. But with my code it show all the items include the past items.

Can someone tells my, how to show only upcoming items?

```
<?php
                              query_posts('post_type=agenda&&showposts=-1');
                              if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                              <div class="post_page">
                              <h3 class="date"><?php if(get_field('date')) { echo date_i18n("l d F Y",strtotime(get_field('date'))); } else { the_time('l d F Y'); } ?></h3>
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Lees meer...</a>
                                </div>
                     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

from **[the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Combining_Parameters)** seems you can add a clause to `query_posts()`.

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580600/wordpress-add-filter-to-query-posts-to-only-show-posts-with-date-set-to-today#answer-15583501)